# protractor: onPrepare for different test suites

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have onPrepare in my conf.js file where I log in to the application.  My understanding is every time I run 1 or more test suites, it first executes whatever is in onPrepare.  This is great, as I use onPrepare to log into the application before running the tests.

Issue is, I don't want to login when I run my login-spec.js suite.

I could first logout before running through login-spec.js, but there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need a place for suite-specific preparations.

This is what `jasmine` can help you with.

For `jasmine` 2.1 and above, there are built-in [`beforeAll` and `afterAll`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown) notations:

> The beforeAll function is called only once before all the specs in
>   describe are run, and the afterAll function is called after all specs
>   finish. These functions can be used to speed up test suites with
>   expensive setup and teardown.

If you are on an older `jasmine` version, use a separate [`jasmine-beforeAll` package](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll).

Comment: Thanks for this.  How do I know which version of jasmine I'm using?  I followed the installation directions for protractor from http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial

Comment: or more importantly, how do I upgrade to 2.1 :)

Comment: @Jason what is the output of `npm list jasmine-core`?

Comment: jasmine-core@2.1.3, but, when I do this 'console.log('jasmine-version:' + jasmine.getEnv().versionString());', it prints 1.3.  odd.

Comment: my package.json file is showing "jasmine-core": "~2.1.2".  I guess this means I'm running 2.1

Comment: It's telling me beforeAll is not defined, so I'm not on 2.1.  Strange that npm list jasmine-core tells me it's 2.1

Comment: @Jason I suspect it is not in the core yet, use `jasmine-beforeAll` please. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/362  Jasmine2 only made it a few days ago.

Comment: @Jason good to know and thanks for sharing! Have you tried `jasmine-beforeAll`?

Comment: Not yet.  I got caught up with other tests :)  Ill give it a try later today

Comment: As explained in the other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835554/protractor-jasmine-showing-different-versions-what-am-i-doing-wrong/27847995#27847995, you have to specify which Jasmine version you want to use, as protractor does not force you onto jasmine 2.x