# Protractor/Jasmine showing different versions - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor

When I do this:

```
console.log('jasmine-version:' + jasmine.getEnv().versionString());
```

it prints: jasmine-version:1.3.1 revision 1354556913

When I run 'npm list jasmine-core' it prints:

```
server@0.0.1 /Users/xx/Desktop/workingDirectory
└── jasmine-core@2.1.3
```

Why is one showing 2.1.3 and another showing 1.3.1?

I don't seem to have the features in 2.1.3, so it's running 1.3.1.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify that you want to use jasmine2 in the conf file. Please read the docs here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/jasmine-upgrade.md#in-your-conf-file.

Protractor supports both jasmine 1.3 and 2.x, and it's up to you to specify the version of jasmine you want to use. (Side note, 2.x is provided via jasmine-core, while 1.3 is provided via minijasminenode)

EDIT: another side note, protractor support for 2.x is not released until protractor 1.6 or if you use master

Answer (score 1):

This is my issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/362

Looks like Jasmine2 was only checked in a few days ago.