# How to test angular views accessible after a login?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am using protractor to test my angular app, where most of the views are accessible for authenticated users only.

Currently, I placed the login action in `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get(site + '/account/login');
    element(by.id('Username')).sendKeys('testuser');
    element(by.id('Password')).sendKeys('letmein');
    element(by.css('[value="Log In"]')).click();
});
```

The problem is for every `it('should....')` test, the webdriver visits the login page and perform the same log in ritual over and over again.

I guess there must be a better way to do it. How can we set up correctly so that the webdriver login only once and then perform all the `it('should....')` tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via the `onPrepare` field of the protractor configuration file.

An [example configuration file with login](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js) is provided in Protractor itself.

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.driver.get(env.baseUrl + '/login.html');

  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('Jane');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('1234');
  ...
```

}

Alternatively, you can make use of the fact that Jasmine tests are ordered. Thus, instead of logging in before every test,  you can have your first `it` login.

I typically organize my Jasmine tests into larger suites, with the first `it` signing in, and the last `it` signing off.

The obvious disadvantage is that your tests are not entirely independent, but in return test execution is substantially faster. You can even argue that doing multiple things after logging in is more realistic than logging on and off for every action.

Yet another solution is to use the Jasmine 2.x beforeAll and afterAll notations of (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27833511/165292)). This does require that you use the newest version of Protractor, as pre 1.5 versions of Protractor only worked with Jasmine 1.x.

Comment: I find it is not possible to test multiple user roles in the `onPrepare` config section. So +1 for the "Alternatively".

Comment: FYI, in case of Jasmine 1.x, [`jasmine-beforeAll`](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll) package can be used.